# JPA/Hibernate performance

Tags: java, sql-server, performance, hibernate, jpa

My Java EE application works with rather large relational DB of two tables app. of 3.5 mln rows each. The two tables are named, say, 'User' and 'Device' - one to many with FK on 'Device' table. 
I need to extract devices for user. The query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Device d WHERE d.user_id = 'some_id'
```

I am using SQL Server 2012, and this query needs less than 1 ms to run. But when I use Criteria API or JPQL or Native JPA Query it needs more than 1 second!

If I store a Collection in a Users's class and fetch the devices lazily, it needs over 200 ms.

I am using Hibernate.

Maybe there is a lack of information to answer my question, if so, please, say what information should be provided by me.

So, what may be the reason of such low performance and what are the main patterns when working with large data sets (3.5 mln, as I mentioned) with JPA?

Sry for poor English.

upd.
The code, that needs 200 ms

```
Collection<Device> userDevices = user.getDevices();
for (Device device : userDevices) {
    if (device.getActive() && device.isToken())
        sender.sendSms(user.getMobilePhone(), text); // costs 0, i am using a stub
}
```

And the User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    //bla bla bla
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Device> devices;
    //bla bla bla

    public Collection<Device> getDevices() {
        return devices;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `index` your data?

Comment: In the case when I have a Collection<Device> link in a User class the Index on FK slows down the performance from 200 ms to 500 ms.

Comment: Indexed or not, JPA deals with Java objects and to imagine there will be no overhead in transforming hundreds, thousands or even millions of rows in a ResultSet to a collection of Java objects is a little naive. If you have specific concerns you will need to post some code and your mappings and some timings.

Comment: How many devices does your user 'some_id' have? Are we talking O(10) or O(10000)? What are the SQL queries executed by Hibernate in your test case? Are you sure you're not measuring the time used to open the connection inside your code? Or the time used to create the session factory? Post the code of your test case.

Comment: Each User has from 0 to 3 devices (inclusive). Hibernate translates all my requests to a query, that is very similar to the one presented above, except it explicitly lists all the column names of Device (against my star-symbol). The code, that I am measuring I've added to the end of main post.

Comment: Please try logging Hibernate's SQL queries. Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html, performance issues are usually best resolved when you know what SQL Hibernate is actually sending to your database.

Comment: I'm no SQLServer expert, but there's no reason for the code to take that long provided that an index exists on `device.userId`, and the database does use this index. My guess is that the non-parameterized query uses a cache/index that the parameterized query used by Hibernate doesn't use. There's no way Hibernate takes 200 ms. to create three instances of Device. So either the database is to blame, or `sender.sendSms()` is the one taking so much time.

Comment: sender.sendSms() is just a stub, it does not take any time. My English is not very good and I've misunderstood your thought about cache/index. You meant, that SQLServer does not use the index for my query? Do not really know, but one strange thing is that when I am creating an index for Device table FK (user_id), the performance slows down more than 2 times - from 200 ms for that code to 500 ms.

Comment: You should tag your question with the sql-server tag, so that sql-server experts can explain this behavior. Provide all the necessary information in the question: how are the tables defined, the indices, what are the SQL queries executed by the Hibernate during the test case.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a JPQL query, the result itself is not necessarily the only thing that is fetched from the database (you don't necessarily query for a single).

If your `Device` class has a reference to a `User`(or many), the `User` will also be loaded when you query for the `Device`. Also, there is some overhead associated with instantiating objects and registering them in the `EntityManager`(although I suspect that this overhead is not that large.)

In essence, you can't expect a JPQL query to run as fast as a SQL query, since they are far from the same, even though they are syntactically similar.

If you write a native sql query and run it through Hibernate I would expect it to take about as much time as running a sql query directly.

When it comes to lazy loading, Hibernate needs to revisit the database in order to retrieve the lazily loaded entities, which of course will take some time. You save time loading the owning object, but the time saved is spent once you try to load the lazy-fetched association (although, from what I've seen, eager fetch takes about as much time as lazy fetch and then lazy load, only a few ms separate the two..)

If you want to see the sql that Hibernate generates based on your JPQL query add `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>` to your Hibernate config, and the following to your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: The joke is that a native SQL query to fetch a user's devices needs more that 1 second to complete. While the same query, made from the SQLServer console needs less than 1 millisecond. Perhaps, Hibernate reopens the connection for each query.

Comment: I would then check my SQL driver. Use the jTDS driver, the one from Microsoft has a lot of quirks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Java sends parameters of queries in Unicode, and SQLServer has to transalte all the columns to Unicode too. Setting the sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false parameter to connection in persistence.xml will help.
The piece of code, that costed 200 ms, now costs only 2-5 ms. 
Unfortunately, I spent 2 days to find the reason, as I thought, the problem was in Hibernate. 
See: http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2014-05-01/java/fixing-slow-queries-running-sql-server-using-jpa-hibernate-and-jtds

Comment: This is not a good answer. It's OK to answer his own questions, but the answer should provide the explanation, not just a link to somewhere else.